# MustacheJS doesn't render values of functions calling other functions

Tags: javascript, templates, mustache

I have a simple MustacheJS template:

```
<script id="myTpl" type="text/template">
  <div id="metrics">
    <div>
      <p>Votes: {{ votes.total }}</p>
      <p>Men: {{ votes.men }}</p>
      <p>Women: {{ votes.women }}</p>
      <p>Unknowns: {{ votes.unknown }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</script>

<div id="container">
</div>
```

And there is a JavaScript code:

```
var data = {
  votes: {
    total: function() {
      return this.voters.men.length + this.voters.women.length + this.voters.unknown.length;
      //return this.votes.men() + this.votes.women() + this.votes.unknown();
    },
    men: function() {
      return this.voters.men.length;
    },
    women: function() {
      return this.voters.women.length;
    },
    unknown: function() {
      return this.voters.unknown.length;
    }
  },
  voters: {
    men: [
      "hpiotrekh",
      "goferek",
      "Carlos_Irwin_Estevez",
      "Nemezis_"
    ],
    women: [],
    unknown: [
      "komurczak",
      "PLDami"
    ]
  }
}

var template = $('#myTpl').html();
var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
$('#container').html(html);
```

In the case when second return statement in votes.total function is commented and we use the first return of that function everything works. But when I try to use the second return statement that uses functions of the object it belongs to, the code doesn't render.

I can't understand why.

Live demo https://jsfiddle.net/bxgnd7ch/

Just comment 4th line and uncomment 5th.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error caused by function context changed, the actually problem is that you are calling object function by caller `this.votes`

In total() function

```
this.voters.men.length + this.voters.women.length + this.voters.unknown.length;
```

the context `this` is pointing to `data`

The problem is :

```
return this.votes.men() + this.votes.women() + this.votes.unknown()
```

you invoked `this.votes.men()` by caller `this.votes`,the context `this` is pointing to `data.votes`
so the context in men/women/unknown function

```
this === data.votes
```

Thats why the when the men() function trying to access

```
this.voters.men.length
```

its actually accessing `data.votes.voters.men.length`

but you expected to access `data.voters.men.length`

so this cause the error.

## Solution:

Try to extract the `voters` out of `data` object, 
if you really have to call object function inside of object function

it will be like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/bxgnd7ch/3/

Comment: It is a bit complicated but I slowly understand it. The code above is just a part of larger template and I need object voters to be passed to the template also. So I cannot exclude it from the data object. Or maybe there is some more sophisticated way to do that.

Comment: You also can use this.votes.men.call(this) in the total function to bind the context with 'data'
Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/bxgnd7ch/4/

Comment: That's the better way, thanks. Isn't it strange that invoking 'this' within 'votes' object, refers to overriding 'data' object?